# ng-select - when dropdown is opened it is scrolled far-down by default

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select for dropdown list (multiselect).
ng-select has native problem so when all items are auto-selected on dropdown init, it will be auto-scrolled far-down to last item.

It is working when no items are preselected on init but I need them all to be preselected on init.

Is there a chance to avoid this behavior?

Comment: your edit queue is full.  People try to edit to attract more visitors to your topic, or ensure a better match between "your problem" and the potential knowledge of visitors. It's an active tool to help you, IT'S NOT THERE to correct you. Please consider accepting some edits.

Comment: I didn't get any edit notif on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Could this approach work?

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'myForm',
    templateUrl: './myForm.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./myForm.component.scss']
})

export class AlarmComponent implements OnInit {
myForm: FormGroup;
dropdownitems: [];

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {this.initializeForm();}

initializeForm() {this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({myDropdown: [''] });
```

html-file

```
<div class="card text-center> 
    <form [formGroup]=" myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="col-xl-12">
<ng-select [items]= dropdownitems"                                                        formControlName="alarm" > </ng-select> 
<!-- bindValue="" bindLabel="" (change)="onChanged($event)"are optional --> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If this doesn't fit your needs, please add the html- and the ts-template (complete) to your question. Or a link to somewhere where they can be found.

Take care and good luck.